# What diameter pipe do I need to adjust this basin waste pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

I fitted a new tap and waste outlet to a small basin, because the new outlet is shorter than the old, the plastic pipework no longer reaches (see photo) I can force the parts to mate but I don't like having the pipe under a lot of strain and it doesn't seal properly (I havent tried applying copious amounts of plumbers putty).

[image: pipework]

I am considering cutting off the white-painted down-pipe (at right of photo) and using a solvent-weld straight coupling to insert a new section of pipe to raise the pipework about 1 cm.

The existing pipe has an outside diameter of 36 mm.
The pipes available in catalogues are listed as 32 mm or 40 mm.

I understand that a nominal 32 mm plastic waste pipe has an outside diameter of 34.5 mm. Is this the right pipe?

Comment: I am a little concerned about those 2 90 degree bends that are visible.  Those look like vent 90s that should not be used to waste.  IMO they should be smoothe bends instead of sharp corners.

Comment: @auujay: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I think this may reflect a difference in plumbing practices in the US and UK. The bend on the left is part of a standard "P trap" basin waste outlet ([example](http://www.screwfix.com/p/tubular-swivel-p-trap-32mm/17159?cm_mmc=GoogleBase-_-Datafeed-_-Heating%20and%20Plumbing-_-Tubular%20Swivel%20P%20Trap%2032mm)) and the bend on the right is also a fairly common part marketed for basin waste pipes ([example](http://www.screwfix.com/p/floplast-90-bend-white-32mm-pack-of-5/78220?_requestid=575769))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Cut where marked, but adjust the location so you've got clearance to work later.

Seeing as you only need a couple of millimeters, you might be able to get away with buying only the coupling connector similar to this:

[image]

So a good straight cut where marked, insert the connect and solvent weld it back into place.

Take the cut piece in with you, and just make sure you've got a snug dry fit in the store.
No need to actually figure out the exact diameter.  Just buy the piece that fits.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to try sanding off the gloss paint from the pipe before welding.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have discovered there are at least two incompatible types of "32mm" plastic waste pipe.

- "**solvent weld**" PVC or ABS pipe with an inside diameter of **32mm** and outside diameter of **~37mm**.
- "**push fit**" plastic pipe with an inside diameter of **~29mm** and an outside diameter of **~35mm**

Because of the difference in diameters, you can't use push-fit fittings on "solvent weld" pipe and you can't use solvent-weld fittings on push-fit pipe. I guess this is deliberate to stop people trying to use solvent to weld a pipe made of a material that the solvent won't melt.

<sub>Diameters above are approximate measurements made with a cheap vernier gauge.</sub>